# pandas.read_excel column as int64 with NA values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to import an excel spreadsheet onto pandas using:

```
df= pd.read_excel(excel_file)
```

This reads integer columns fine as int64, as long as they don't have missing or nan values. When they do have nan values it is read as float64.

I have tried using:

```
df= pd.read_excel(excel_file, converters={'column_x': np.int64, 'column_y': np.int64})
```

and

```
df= pd.read_excel(excel_file, dtype={'column_x': np.int64, 'column_y': np.int64})
```

I'd like to keep the missing values as nan but the other values as int.
Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in pandas 0.24+ with [Nullable integer data type](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html):

```
df= pd.read_excel(excel_file, dtype={'column_x': 'Int64', 'column_y': 'Int64'})
```